# Django not importing CSS

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I cannot get the CSS to appear when I refresh the page nor when I turn the server off and then restart it.

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name='viewpoint' content='width-device-width, initial-scale-1.0'>
  <meta http-equix='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie-edge'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css"/>
  <link ref="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" />
```

My settings.py file has STATIC_URL = '/static/'

I'm not sure what else it could be. I've attempted several other stackoverflow questions but I'm out of ideas.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show me your logs?

Comment: Souldn't it be `{% load static %}` [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#static) . In older versions (v1.10-)  you'll have to import `{% load static from staticfiles %}`? Correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: Have you run collect static method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **setting.py** file your set `DEBUG=True`, please update **url.py** file root (**url.py** project)

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static 
urlpatterns = [  
  #url pattern..... 
]
if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and than if `DEBUG=False` `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['your_host']`, please running command **./manage.py collectstatic** from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your `urls.py` you did not import `from django.conf import settings` and/or 
`from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns`
and you did not add `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` in your `urls.py` too.

And maybe your first css (I mean `<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css"/>`)
 Blocks your second css. Try to comment your first css and check is it working.